# Missing C# Possible null reference assignment error in protobuf message

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, nullable

I have a custom message type which serves as a wrapper for `byte` in order to avoid casting in the application code and show the intended value range explicitly.

I use that in a message declared as below:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message ByteWrapper{
   int32 Value = 1;
}

message TestMessage{
    ByteWrapper MyField = 1;
}
```

I have the some logic declared for the generated classes (constructor and casting):

```cs
public partial class ByteWrapper
{
    private ByteWrapper(byte value) => Value = value;

    public static implicit operator byte(ByteWrapper value) { return (byte)value.Value; }
    public static implicit operator ByteWrapper(byte value) { return new ByteWrapper(value); }
}
```

I wonder - **why do I not get the `possible null reference assignment` error in the constructor of the protobuf-based class**, even though I can assign a null there.

```cs
public partial class TestMessage 
{
    public TestMessage(byte? input)
    {
        MyField = input; //no warning here
    }
}

public class SomeNormalClass
{
    public SomeNormalClass(byte? input)
    {
        MyField = input; //possible null reference assignment error here
    }

    public ByteWrapper MyField { get; }
}
```

The error appears properly in the class that is not based on protobuf message, but I cannot find out **what exactly is there in the protobuf generated code that prevents the compiler from displaying this warning**...
Also it seems like an incorrect behaviour, as far as I understand.

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies this warning does not apply to generated code so it also does not apply to classes generated from proto.